# How to get the number of characters (ignoring spaces) in a div with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

Basically, if I have:

```
<div id="dummy">hey, what's up !!! !!</div>
```

I would do something like:

```
let x = document.getElementByID("dummy").length();
```

And `x` should be equal to `17` (ignoring the spaces).

How can I do this with JavaScript? I'm searched, but the only solutions I can find are made with jQuery and I'd like to do it without it.

Comment: document.getElementByID("dummy").innerText.length;

Comment: So you're asking how to retrieve an element's text, and you didn't find anything? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: If there is no choice : `/<([\w:]+)(?=\s)(?=((?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\sid\s*=\s*(['"])\s*dummy\s*\3(?:\s+(?=((?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!\/>)[^>])?)+))\4)?\s*>))\2\s*([\S\s]*?)\s*<\/\1\s*>/g`

https://regex101.com/r/4IuVzk/1

and the text is in capture group 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the properties you are looking for are [`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) or [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and [`string.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length).

If you want to ignore the spaces, then you can use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove them using the `/\s/g` [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to match all the spaces:

```js
console.log(`Length is ${ document.getElementById('text').textContent.replace(/\s/g, '').length }.`);
```

```html
<div id="text">hey, what's up !!! !!</div>
```

Note the result with `.innerText` and `.textContent` will not match if there's content that is not visible, but otherwise `.textContent` performs better and is more consistent across browsers.

There's a really good explanation about that in this article @skyline3000 posted in a comment: https://kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/

```js
console.log(`Length is ${ document.getElementById('text').innerText.replace(/\s/g, '').length } (using .innerText).`);
console.log(`Length is ${ document.getElementById('text').textContent.replace(/\s/g, '').length } (using .textContent).`);
```

```html
<div id="text">hey, what's up<span style="display: none; "> !!! !!</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply need `textContent` property from element

```js
const el = document.getElementById("dummy")
console.log(`Length is ${el.textContent.length}`)
```

```html
<div id="dummy">hey, what's up !!! !!</div>
```

Comment: You should really use `textContent` which doesn't cause the browser to do a layout pass: https://kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/

Comment: yeah, for some reason it gives a different result if I use textContent and innerText

Comment: yep, `innerText` doesn't work well with child elements

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = document.querySelector("#dummy").innerText.split("").filter(removeSpace).length;
function removeSpace(str) {
  return str !== " ";
}
console.log(str);
```

```html
<div id="dummy">hey, what's up !!! !!</div>
```

Comment: No need to create an array to do that, but in any case, if you do, you don't need to use `.join('')` at the end, you can just get the `.length` property on the filtered array.